# Universal codec for recording video with opencv and playing it in browser

Tags: html, opencv, video, codec, recording

I'm trying to do a recording system with OpenCV. I use it to record videos.

Here is an example:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPEG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('example.mkv',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It is a recording system  and I can't use the mp4 container and Its codecs, because:

- In case of unplanned problems, the recording could not end correctly and will be corrupted.
- I make 5-minutes recordings and while one recording won't be finished, you can't play it.

That's why I use **mkv** or **avi** and **mjpg** codec.
The recording works well. I can play video on my computer, but it can't be played in the browser using the **video** element because it doesn't support  **mkv** or **avi** container and **mjpg** codec. Unfortunately, I don't have enough powerful machines to recode video with a codec. I use **ffmpeg** to do it and I should pass the `-vcodec copy` param to speed up this process. In other cases, it will be too slow. Is there a universal codec and container that can be used to save recordings and that will be valid for browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Use PyAV. it's a wrapper around ffmpeg for python. you need some flexibility here. ffmpeg/PyAV give you that. ffmpeg lets you use hardware encoding, if it is available and you ask for that. OpenCV's purpose isn't encoding video, it's computer vision.

use MPEG *Transport Streams* (`.ts`). that's what HLS streaming uses. if a browser can't handle it natively, there is javascript that can. transport streams also have the advantage that you can butcher them any which way and they're still recoverable, apart from the butchered parts. MP4 can't be repaired in general, only if specific conditions are met. TS needs no repairing in the first place.

use H.264. it's fairly compatible and the closest to "universal" you'll get today, in practical terms. you should encode Intra-only if you value recoverability.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a universal codec and container that can be used for save recording and that will be valid for browsers?

Yes, container mp4, videocodec libx264, if you have main.mkv or main.avi use it

```
ffmpeg -i main.mkv -c:v libx264 -crf 17  -b:v 6000k -maxrate  6000K -bufsize 4M   -movflags -faststart  -preset veryfast -dn  ./video.mp4
```

---

PARAMETERS FOR QUALITY AND FAST ENCODE

1. -crf scale 0–51, where 0 is lossless, 23 is the default, and 51 is worst quality possible. A lower value generally leads to higher quality, and a subjectively sane range is 17–28. Consider 17 or 18 to be visually lossless or nearly so; it should look the same or nearly the same as the input but it isn't technically lossless.
2. -b:v kBit/s video bitrate
3. -preset for encoding speed, ultrafast superfast veryfast faster fast medium (default preset) slow slower veryslow

Answer (score 0):

Most devices and browser only supports hardware decodable codecs, which are: h264/h265 (HEVC) with `.mp4/.mov` container and vp8/vp9 `.webm` container. Both would be corrupted if not finalized correctly. In the future there will be AV1. So don't rely on MJPEG, PNG e.t.c codecs and containers like AVI. What you can do, though is repair mp4 file with the tool [untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc), when MP4 is not written correctly main issue would be with MOOV atom.